# How to inject dotenv variables without REACT_APP prefix in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, dotenv

I have a project to migrate from legacy React app to standard `create-react-app` one (not ejected).

In legacy project, it manually loads `.env` files with `dotenv` and `dotenv-expand` and injects through webpack `DefinePlugin`.

`create-react-app` intuitively supports `dotenv` but can only recognize variables with `REACT_APP_` prefix.

There are so many places in legacy code also along with imported packages in other repositories that are using `process.env.xxx` variables, so it is impossible for now to rename them with prefix before migration.

In this case, how can I make `create-react-app` recognize dotenv variables without `REACT_APP_` prefix?

BTW, I tried to `rewire` build script before with some simple customizations over webpack, like bundling js and css:

```
const path = require('path');
const rewire = require('rewire');
const defaults = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js');

let webpackConfig = defaults.__get__('config');

webpackConfig.output.filename = 'static/js/[name].js';
webpackConfig.optimization.splitChunks = { cacheGroups: { default: false } };
webpackConfig.optimization.runtimeChunk = false;
webpackConfig.plugins.find(plugin => plugin.__proto__.constructor.name === 'MiniCssExtractPlugin').options.filename = 'static/css/[name].css';
webpackConfig.plugins.find(plugin => plugin.__proto__.constructor.name === 'MiniCssExtractPlugin').options.moduleFilename = () => 'static/css/[name].css';
```

But it seems `dotenv` and `DefinePlugin` are more complicated. Not sure if it can be achieved in the same way.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good option in your situation, but what if you defined all your variables using both naming styles? (e.g. `FOO=bar` and `REACT_APP_FOO=bar`)

Comment: I've reviewed the source-code of cra, it is not possible to change the prefix of `REACT_APP_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also use `rewire`

```
// "start": "node start.js"
const rewire = require('rewire');

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

let getClientEnvironment = rewire('react-scripts/config/env.js');
getClientEnvironment.__set__(
  'REACT_APP',
  /(^REACT_APP_|API|DEPLOY|SECRET|TOKEN|URL)/,
);

let configFactory = rewire('react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');
configFactory.__set__('getClientEnvironment', getClientEnvironment);

let start = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/start.js');
start.__set__('configFactory', configFactory);
```

`build` is a little bit different

```
// "build": "node build.js"
const rewire = require('rewire');

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

let getClientEnvironment = rewire('react-scripts/config/env.js');
getClientEnvironment.__set__(
  'REACT_APP',
  /(^REACT_APP_|API|DEPLOY|SECRET|TOKEN|URL)/,
);

let configFactory = rewire('react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');
configFactory.__set__('getClientEnvironment', getClientEnvironment);

let webpackConfig = configFactory('production');

let build = rewire('react-scripts/scripts/build.js');
build.__set__('config', webpackConfig);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Years ago](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2865#issuecomment-325687166) Dan Abramov (co-creator of CRA) suggested to redefine the variables to fit `REACT_APP_` in an entrypoint script that then calls react-scripts in package.json.

If you have simpler needs to support these variables, such as CI platform variables like Netlify's `COMMIT_REF` or Gitlab's `CI_COMMIT_SHA`, you could set those variables inline without adding another script.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "REACT_APP_COMMIT_SHA=$COMMIT_REF$CI_COMMIT_SHA react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

This will set `REACT_APP_COMMIT_SHA` to the value of the hash of whichever service it's built in (since the other variable will be empty).

Answer (score 1):

My solution is create config-overrides.js and modify process.env when build time.
You still defined REACT_APP_[VARIABLE NAME] in your env file, and remove prefix when build time.

```js
// config-overrides.js
const {
    override,
} = require('customize-cra');
const ENV_PREFIX = /^REACT_APP_/i;

const findWebpackPlugin = (plugins, pluginName) =>
    plugins.find((plugin) => plugin.constructor.name === pluginName);

const overrideProcessEnv = () => (config) => {
    const plugin = findWebpackPlugin(config.plugins, 'DefinePlugin');
    const processEnv = plugin.definitions['process.env'] || {};

    const transformedEnv = Object.keys(processEnv)
        .filter((key) => ENV_PREFIX.test(key))
        .reduce((env, key) => {
            const craKey = key.replace('REACT_APP_', '');
            env[craKey] = processEnv[key];
            return env;
        }, {});

    plugin.definitions['process.env'] = {
        ...processEnv,
        ...transformedEnv,
    };

    return config;
};
module.exports = override(
  overrideProcessEnv()
)
```

Comment: Can you please add more detail to this. I want to use it but it doesn't work off the bat. What are the additional config steps to get it to work?